# Formhelper does not output form element in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Hello I have a problem related to my cakephp application.  I am using php version 5.6 and cakephp version 2.8.

The problem I am having is when I use this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Subsubcategory.subsubcat_name',
         array('type' => 'text',
              'required'=>true,
              'class' => 'input-xlarge',
              'div' => array('class' => 'control-group'),
              'label' => array('class' => 'control-label','text' => 'Subsubcategory Name : ')
        ));
```

I get the following errors:
[image: warning image]

What I am missing?

Comment: Have you included the Form helper in the `$helpers` array in the controller?

Comment: Yes I included but same error

Comment: And are you sure you are using cakephp 2.8 versions ?

Comment: Show how you include `formHelper` in controller

Comment: Can you please show the whole view file or the whole form?